# Nhibernate QueryOver: Count in where clause

Tags: nhibernate

Any tips on how to convert the following to QueryOver:

```
 var widget = session.Query<Widget>()
                    .Fetch(x => x.NotificationJobs)
                    .Where(x =>
                        x.Status == Status.Active &&
                        !x.NotificationJobs.Any())
                    .OrderByDescending(x => x.DateCreated)
                    .Take(1)
                    .SingleOrDefault();
```

Want to get a widget that has no notification jobs.

Answer (score 0):

```
var widgetWithNoNotificationJob = session.QueryOver<Widget>()
    .Where( x => x.Status == Status.Active )
    .OrderBy( x => x.DateCreated ).Desc
    .Left.JoinQueryOver<NotificationJob>( x => x.NotificationJobs )
        .Where( x => x.NotificationJobId == null )
    .Take( 1 )
    .SingleOrDefault();
```

This will produce SQL with a LEFT OUTER JOIN on the NotificationJob table and a WHERE clause with NotificationJob.NotificationJobId IS NULL.

Hopefully this will point you in the right direction.